# My laptop automatically shuts down when I play CSGO

Tags: shutdown, laptop, steam, amd-graphics

As the title says my laptop immediately shuts down when I enter CS:GO game.

I launch steam with "launch with dedicate graphic card" and play CS:GO from the library everything works fine in the lobby until I enter the game then my laptop shuts down.

Comment: That is often caused due to a violation of memory access. Could be faulty memory. Check your logs in /var/log/ for reasons for the crash; you need to find an error we can explain. As the question is now ... not really anything we can do.

Answer (score 0):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.